# How to migrate Mercurial hg repo to GitHub using online import engine

Tags: github, mercurial, migrate

I am trying to use the online (official) GitHub import engine to migrate this Mercurial repo http://hg.code.sf.net/p/amide/code/ to GitHub. However, I get the following error:

```
No source repositories were detected at http://hg.code.sf.net/p/amide/code. Please check the URL and try again.
```

Any idea about what I am doing wrong?

Steps to reproduce:

- Go to https://github.com/new/import
- Paste in the clone url http://hg.code.sf.net/p/amide/code
- Click on begin import

Comment: It gives you the reason in the error message there is no source code at the page and if you look at the page, there is no source code just list of commits.  You have to read the GitHub engine information what exactly it does need - for us to help you we need a description step-by-step what you did.

Comment: I have edited the post and added now the steps. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the GitHub online importer is not compatible with some Mercurial repository servers.

Instead, one has to use the command line, see:
https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/source-code-migration-tools#importing-from-mercurial

I used the nice conversion script from this repository: https://github.com/frej/fast-export

and was able to get the repo cleanly converted into https://github.com/ferdymercury/amide

Comment: Ah, you are directly using the Github importer.  That is only for git, naturally it can't import mercurial.

Comment: Not  true. I have tried with some other mercurial repos on other servers and it imports well with the online importer. They specifically say the following in https://github.com/new/import if you click on supported VCS:
"Supported version control:
We support importing repositories from Git, Subversion, Mercurial, and TFS. Here are some example urls.

    https://example.com/svn/ <= Don’t include trunk or branches
    https://example.com/hg
    https://tfs.example.com/tfs <= We’ll figure out which project next

"